# UI dialog buttons hide controls

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm a beginner of JQueryUI and probably I forget something very simple...

There is a way to show controls made by a plugin like [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) inside a dialog wihout have to scroll the dialog body?

If you check this http://jsfiddle.net/WJUnc/1/, when you select month the dropdown list is hidden by the buttons bar. I'd like that the select list is open outside the dialog body container. Is it possible?

the only solution I find is to increase the height of the dialog like this:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 500
    });
```

I get the same experience with other plugins.

Comment: Do you mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7fuz2/

Comment: Sergio, Archer made the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh... jQueryUI.  Both a blessing and a curse!  Add this css and it should solve the problem...

```
#dialog, .dialog, .ui-dialog
{
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

**[Here's a working jsFiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/WJUnc/3/)**

Comment: No problem.  Manipulating the CSS for jQueryUI can be somewhat demanding at times.  Glad to help :)